# TPanel in Embarcadero Rad Studio

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a TMapView. Above the TPanel. Problem is that the map visible through the TPanel. How to make background non-transparent for TPanel

Comment: TPanel should cover the TMapView without any problems. Now if you have placed TMapView on your form after placing the TPanel it is possible that TMapView has higher Z order and is therefore shown above the TPanel. You can correct this by Right-clicking on your TPanel and then chose Control->Bring to front.

Answer (score 1):

There are no way to show panel (or any other **styled** FMX control) on the TMapView, TWebBrowser, other controls with ControlType = Platform (like TEdit) on mobile platforms.

TMapView is a wrapper around native control. Native controls always shown on top of form because of differences in the mechanism of rendering. Like in VCL, TEdit always displayed above TLabel, because TEdit is descendant of TCustomControl, which painting controlled by OS, and TLabel is descendant of TGraphicControl, which painting controlled by form.

If you want to show some controls above TMapView/TWebBrowser, etc..., you should use only native controls.

a good explanation is given on http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/fmxicl.asp